Элемент поля формы не имеет ни атрибута id, ни атрибута имени после интеграции Emoji Mart
Я пытаюсь интегрировать Emoji Mart в проект, но во время теста я увидел в консоли следующие сообщения, поэтому хочу спросить, это нормально или нужно это исправить?

A form field element has neither an id nor a name attribute. This
might prevent the browser from correctly autofilling the form. To fix
this issue, add a unique id or name attribute to a form field. This is
not strictly needed, but still recommended even if you have an
autocomplete attribute on the same element. 541 resources Read more:
Form input elements


Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
